# How can we extract some data from pdf based on some condition derived from it's sub data

Tags: javascript, python, java, pdf

Let's assume I'm having a pdf with the following data
[image]

Now, My requirement is to extract column names based on it's sub-data
i.e., from pdf we need to check what are the columns having Nullable 'Y' and need to extract those column names.

how can we achieve it.

Comment: Please only add relevant tags.

Answer (score 1):

see `pdfminer` module for python. returns you a dictionary of the entire page which you can leverage in a solution, also can return XML style similar to pdf markup